# Is Visual Studio 2010 CTP stable for everyday use?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I know it's still in CTP, but is Visual Studio 2010 stable enough for everyday use? Are there any gotchas to watch out for, like .sln conversions that aren't backward-compatible with VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say that the Team Editions - Architect and Test - are definitely **not**.  That's not to say that they don't look great - but in a very good demo given by [Mickey Goussett](http://teamsystemrocks.com/), they crashed or had some significant problems multiple times (particularly in the test reproducing features and the architect diagrams).

Play with it, but I wouldn't recommend it for production code.

Comment: Hi Matt, can you please post the link of the webcast? Couldn't find it. Was it taken offline?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I was under the impression that it expires very soon (like, this month).

Comment: there is a patch from Microsoft to avoid that ;)

Comment: If by patch you mean instructions to set the system date back in time on the VPC image and to disable automatic synchronization of the VPC's date/time with the host's (instructions at http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/11/28/disabling-time-synchronization-under-virtual-pc-2007.aspx).